# Category for obj-c class derived from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am running project with lots of legacy code with objc and swift.
I've been using objc `MPOldKeychainManager`, which is now deprecated and swift's `NewKeychainManager` is to be used.

The problem is following: `MPOldKeychainManager` had some categories written and I don't want to rewrite them as swift extensions.
What I've done is:

- naming the class derived from the `NewKeychainManager` (visible in "`myTarget-Swift.h`") to "`MPOldKeychainManager`"
- removing the objc declaration of `MPOldKeychainManager`

...hoping that the categories will still work.

```
objc(MPOldKeychainManager)
class NewKeychainManager: KeychainManager {
}
```

Unfortunately, old extensions can't see the `MPOldKeychainManager` (derived from swift), even though I've updated the imported header to `myTarget-Swift.h`

```
#import "myTarget-Swift.h" //previously - objc "MPOldKeychainManager.h"
@interface MPOldKeychainManager (Authentication)
```

Question: is it possible to use categories for objc classes derived from swift?

- I have already tried totally new naming
- I have already tried loads of clean-builds

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't seen it, here is a useful resource for migrating from Objective-C to Swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective_c_code_to_swift . Among other things, it states that one cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.  What you are trying to do is specify a different Objective-C name, `MPOldKeychainManager`, for the `NewKeychainManager` Swift class.

This will, actually, work if you add an ampersand before `objc`, like so:

```
@objc(MPOldKeychainManager)
class NewKeychainManager: KeychainManager {
}
```

You can then use all your existing categories in Objective-C.  You will, however, have a problem using them in Swift, because to be usable in Swift they need to be available in the bridging header, and you won't be able to use the class' Objective-C name (`MPOldKeychainManager`) in the bridging header.

You can, however, write an Objective-C wrapper class that will have a method corresponding to each category method and also taking a `NewKeychainManager` pointer.  A wrapper method can then delegate to the category method, which is available to Objective-C code, so you won't have to re-implement your category methods in Swift.

Let's say an Objective-C category has method `authenticateUser:`:

```
@interface MPOldKeychainManager (Authentication)

-(void)authenticateUser:(int32_t)uid;

@end
```

The method could be wrapped as follows:

```
@interface OldKCMWrapper : NSObject

+(void)authenticateUser:(int32_t)uid withManager:(NewKeychainManager*)inst;

@end
```

This interface declaration must be available, directly or indirectly, via the bridging header.  Then, somewhere in your Objective-C code, the wrapper could be implemented thus:

```
@implementation OldKCMWrapper

+(void)authenticateUser:(int32_t)uid withManager:(MPOldKeychainManager*)inst {
    [inst authenticateUser:uid];
}

@end
```

The wrapper can then be used in Swift code, e.g.:

```
let kcm = NewKeychainManager()
OldKCMWrapper.authenticateUser(321, with: kcm)
```

In fact, the wrapper could be used in a Swift extension of `NewKeychainManager`.  You would still have a Swift extension with equivalents of all the Objective-C category methods, but you would not have to re-implement their code in Swift: methods in the extension would simply delegate to the wrapper.

Hopefully this is helpful.  There are other ways of implementing this idea, possibly more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem was that in the implementation of category to the derived class, MyTarget-Swift.h was not visible. And indeed, it wasn't, since the category was "exported" to Swift via bridging header, causing a circular imports ("Failed to emit precompiled header for bridging header" error). I've implemented somewhat "hacky" solution using selectors based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36688174/3466016