# How to use a swift class reference in a objC class, and an objC reference in that previous swift file simultaneously?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Suppose I have 2 class in a xCode project.
parent.m, and child.swift.

In parent.m
I require child *ref;

in child.swift
I require weak var ref:parent!

I know how to independently use objc class in swift (using bridging header) or vice versa, but they seem to unable to call each other from their classes.
Is there even a way to do it?

edit: the problem is solved. 
Cause:
The problem was a deadlock situation.
in order to use parent.m in child.swift,
I prepared a bridging header and imported parent.m

and in order to use child.swift in parent, I included the system generated  in parent.m .
However the some other prior imports in parent.m were creating the deadlock situation.

Upon moving up the import order of  the problem was solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the both simultaneously"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25670431/1187415 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/q/27761407/1187415